# What is the relationship between the "set system" in graph theory and the one in measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory, graph-theory

In graph theory, a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) is a generalization of a graph in which an edge can join any number of vertices.

A hypergraph is also called a **set system**.

in measure theory, [a set system](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_of_Sets#Also_known_as), is also defined as a set whose elements are themselves all sets, but the implication here is that the sets in question are augmented by the various operations, thus turning such sets of sets into algebraic structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of conventions and expectations. For example, the set system of a hypergraph
may have the property that it is a connected hypergraph. There are other properties that a
set system may satisfy. For example, the set system of a topological space is required to
satisfy certain properties. An alternative approach is to start with a base set and then to
define an indicator function on the power set of the base set. The indicator function has the
value $1$ if and only if the subset is an element of the corresponding set system. Using this
approach we can include other functions on the power set. For example, the
[rank function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_rank) of a matroid is required to
satisfy certain properties. Similarly, in a [meaurable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), the measure function is required to
satisfy certain properties.